# How to test GPS scenarios without going outside in manual testing without going outside (Android/ios)

Tags: android, ios, gps, manual-testing

I'm testing an app in which there are two user roles one is driver and other is the customer.

1. Customer book a ride for sending their goods from one place to
   another.
2. The customer selects pickup point and drops point.
3. When driver start their journey from pickup point to the drop point user will able to see the driver on the map(live tracking)
4. How can I test this live tracking on android and ios without going outside with device?

Comment: By using Fake GPS app you can set a location. You'll have to keep moving  it

Comment: @ Arahasya can you please suggest me some app.

Comment: Search on play store fake gps

Answer (score -1):

you can use fake GPS apps, there are multiple app available on both platform Ios and android. You will have to keep moving it.

Comment: The same was answered by @Arahasya. Your answer does not provide any new information. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer